# How to convert foreign characters in java?

Tags: java, unicode

I've got in input a UNICODE string and I want to convert it into \uxxxx format but if I write this code

```
    String inString = "èaéKlüfsäöråédéroße";
    for (int i = 0; i < inString.length(); i++) {
        Integer charCode = (int)inString.charAt(i);
        result += "\\u" + strlenFix(charCode.toString().toUpperCase());
    }
    static public String strlenFix(String str) {
    while (str.length()<4) str="0"+str;
    return str;
}
```

I have this result:

```
\u65533\u0097\u65533\u0075\u0108\u65533\u0102\u0115\u65533\u65533\u0114\u65533\u65533\u0100\u65533\u0114\u0111\u65533\u0101
```

Comment: It doesn't help that we can't see `strlenFix`. Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: "I want to convert it into \uxxxx format"..."I have this result: `\u0016\u0016\u0016`...am I missing something here?

Comment: @ElGavilan I think he mean everything is `\u0016 `..

Comment: What are expecting from this `charCode.toString(16)` ??

Comment: As mentioned by Jon Skeet - possibly something being messed up by the function strlentFix

Comment: Maybe change charCode.toString(16) to Integer.toString(charCode, 16)?

Comment: EDIT: added strLenfix () and removed "16" in toString(). Now it gives me always back \u65533 foreach special character without any difference, for example, between  ü and ß

Comment: I have just executed every of your codes. Now I obtain \ufffd repeated for every special chars. It doesn't help me

Comment: Well solving this question should be simple. But also important: **why** do you need it in this format? Eg. if it's for writing a JSON file, then use a JSON encoder.

Comment: I need to write an utility for an ESB. It's purpose is to filter special character and if any of them is present in a dictionary they must be translated. This is the full working code http://ideone.com/jmpD0s
THANKS to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Calling static method on reference strikes again!*

Because of it you thought that `charCode.toString(16)` will invoke `toString` *on* `charCode` and return its 16 base version, but it is compiled as `Integer.toString(16)`.

You probably wanted something like `Integer.toString(charCode,16)`.

Comment: I've tried with 
result += "\\u" + strlenFix(Integer.toString(charCode,16)) ;
now for each special chars i've got \ufffd so at the end
\ufffd\u0061\ufffd\u004b\u006c\ufffd\u0066\u0073\ufffd\ufffd\u0072\ufffd\ufffd\u0064\ufffd\u0072\u006f\ufffd\u0065

Comment: @Truman and what is the problem with it? What other results you expected and why?

Comment: If I get the same code for two different characters I think something is going wrong. Is it?

Comment: @Truman I don't get same result as you http://ideone.com/vSTLHg. As you may see in that link for input from your question  `èaéKlüfsäöråédéroße` I got as result `\u00E8\u0061\u00E9\u004B\u006C\u00FC\u0066\u0073\u00E4\u00F6\u0072\u00E5\u00E9\u0064\u00E9\u0072\u006F\u00DF\u0065`. Also notice that this input contains 3x `é` and 2x `r`.

Comment: OMG If I run your code I get
Couldn't add to set: FFFD -> ?
Couldn't add to set: FFFD -> ?
Couldn't add to set: FFFD -> ?
Couldn't add to set: FFFD -> ?
Couldn't add to set: FFFD -> ?
Couldn't add to set: FFFD -> ?
Couldn't add to set: FFFD -> ?
Couldn't add to set: 72 -> r
Couldn't add to set: FFFD -> ?
\uFFFD\u0061\uFFFD\u004B\u006C\uFFFD\u0066\u0073\uFFFD\uFFFD\u0072\uFFFD\uFFFD\u0064\uFFFD\u0072\u006F\uFFFD\u0065

Comment: maybe I've got a problem with Locale settings?

Comment: Switched from IntelliJ to Eclipse....it works as yours. Very very weird! Thank you! :)

Comment: @Truman If that's the case, you may have gotten the encoding of your source file wrong. Make sure your editor and your compiler agree on what encoding to use.

Comment: Indeed I've just re-opened Intellij and what I've found is
String inString = new String("�a�Kl�fs��r��d�ro�e");
while in Eclipse nothing is changed.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String result = "";

     String inString = "èaéKlüfsäöråédéroße";
        for (int i = 0; i < inString.length(); i++) {
            Integer charCode = (int)inString.charAt(i);
            result += "\\u" + Integer.toHexString(charCode) ;
        }
    System.out.println(result);
}

 static public String strlenFix(String str) {
        while (str.length()<4) str="0"+str;
        return str;
    {
```

Comment: ++ for `Integer.toHexString`.

Answer (score 0):

So, just do:

```
public static String unicodeEscaped(char ch) {
  if (ch < 0x10) {
      return "\\u000" + Integer.toHexString(ch);
  } else if (ch < 0x100) {
      return "\\u00" + Integer.toHexString(ch);
  } else if (ch < 0x1000) {
      return "\\u0" + Integer.toHexString(ch);
  }
  return "\\u" + Integer.toHexString(ch);
}
String inString = "èaéKlüfsäöråédéroße";
for (int i = 0; i < inString.length(); i++) {
    Integer charCode = (int)inString.charAt(i);
    result += unicodeEscaped(charCode);
}
```

Comment: the method unicodeEscaped riceve Integer: public static String unicodeEscaped(int ch) {

Answer (score 0):

check out following snippet

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

String result = "";
 String inString = "èaéKlüfsäöråédéroße";
            for (int i = 0; i < inString.length(); i++) {
    result += "\\u" + Integer.toHexString(inString.charAt(i) | 0x10000)+" ";
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those `\uXXXX` escapes normally are followed by a 4-digit *hexadecimal* number.

The simplest way to convert a code point to such an Unicode escape is by using `String.format`:

```
String escaped = String.format("\\u%04X", (int) codePoint);
```

And you can drop your `strlenFix` function, so your loop would just be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inString.length(); i++) {
    result += String.format("\\u%04x", (int) inString.charAt(i));
}
```